# Android studio drawbleLeft

Tags: java, android

Как сместить картинки кнопок правее?

Для отображения картинки использую свойство:

```
android:drawableLeft
```

Так выглядит экран `AndroidStudio` с эмулятором:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Свойства [android:drawablePadding](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawablePadding) вам должно хватить. Дополнительно можете настраивать отступы с помощью:

```
android:paddingLeft
android:paddingRight
```

Если не хватает, добавьте разметку итема полностью.